# Ng-repeat not showing JSON data in Angular-UI

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am trying to pull in data from a JSON file and use it to populate a navigation menu, composed of divs that collapse using the Angular UI collapsible function.

Here is my code ([also on Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XfLGZwZ9LuIjvLmjrUFs?p=info)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="samApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.0.3" data-semver="3.0.3" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div CollapseCtrl navdata ng-repeat="items in item">
        <div class="nav-super">{{items.img}}</div>
              <div collapse="isCollapsed"> 
                  <div class="nav-sub">{{items.img}}</div>
            </div> 
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

My issues are:

- I cannot make the elements within the collapsible take the json information. If I set ng-repeat on one of the divs, the sub or super div will not take it. Setting ng-repeat on the outermost div results in none of the sub divs taking the repeat.
- I have enclosed my controllers in directives and assigned both directives, for the collapsing function and the HTTP GET, to the same div.

Comment: You need to get the data into a controller, not a directive. Attach the controller in your html, and then you can use it wherever. Directives are not for getting data, they are for using it in interesting ways.

Comment: @ZackArgyle If you look at the code, I'm creating controllers inside the directives. I did this so I could run two controllers on the same div and thus perform both the Bootstrap-UI controller and the JSON-Get controller.

Comment: I took a look at your Plunk - your partial code doesn't match your JSON, you're trying to make a controller using a directive, you're trying to bind two scopes to the same element, and your directives don't link anything up. What you're doing seems pretty simple, but maybe you should start off with an angular tutorial?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Thanks. I agree I still have a ton to learn. I had the controllers separated out but couldn't figure out how to add them to the same div structure. Banging my head trying to figure out how this all comes together.

Comment: If you do well with video content there's a lot of them from the Google developers, in particular this was good for me when getting started https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY also checkout egghead.io for bite size videos on various angular topics (isolate scope etc.)

Comment: @shaunhusain Thanks I will watch the Egghead videos and the video you posted. I appreciate it. I read the O'Reilly Angular book but the nuances of this specific case I haven't been able to resolve with searching or tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe you're looking for something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="samApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.0.3" data-semver="3.0.3" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="navDataController">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
          <span ng-click="action(item)">{{item.img}}</span>
              <ul ng-show="item.isCollapsed">
                  <li ng-repeat="sub in item.subcontent">
                    <span>{{sub.title}} {{sub.}}</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
          </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DlVqJOzQwjxdCVjStvZg?p=preview

The example works, but it's a bit crude; learn basics to make it sweet.

Comment: The extra {{sub}} seems errant (posted so this isn't just a thank you). And thank you for making my night.

Answer (score 1):

Also modified your plunkr to work:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jxVGxl7h8gBlFLQ9zyTW?p=preview

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.0.3" data-semver="3.0.3" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="samApp" ng-controller="CollapseCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div class="nav-super" ng-click="item.isCollapsed=!item.isCollapsed">{{item.img}}</div>
              <div collapse="item.isCollapsed">
                  <div class="nav-sub" ng-repeat="subElement in item.subcontent">{{subElement.title}}</div>
            </div> 
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('samApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.service('navdata', function($http) {
  var myServiceObj = {
    myData: {},
    getData: function() {
      $http.get('data.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        angular.copy(data, myServiceObj.myData);

      });
    }
  }
  myServiceObj.getData();
  return myServiceObj;
});
app.controller('CollapseCtrl', function($scope, navdata) {
  $scope.items = navdata.myData;
});
```

Basically directives are meant for adding encapsulated behavior or DOM element manipulation.  I think a service makes more sense for taking care of the requests to the server and storing the data to be used by various controllers.

I also used the data to store the isCollapsed boolean so you may want to loop over the data and set that to false if you want them closed initially or otherwise just reverse your boolean logic in the collapse expression.

You had all the right logic just in the wrong places, also read up on the ng-repeat documentation it's a piece I visit often.